# get sum of mysql table ane joint another tabe for get name

Tags: mysql

```
CSU:                           
   csuid,     csuname,          
   100         china            
    101         england       

    LOAN:
    csuid,  Arears  empid
    100       155   100
    100       250   100
    103       322   100
    103       065   100
```

what is the best way to get sum of arears and group it by csuname..i'm stuck with this

```
slect csuid as csu,sum(arears) as csu_total from loan where empid='100'group by csuid;
```

this works, I can get the csuid, but i want to get csuname for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select CSU.*, sum(loan.Arears) 
from CSU inner join loan on csu.csuid = loan.csuid
group by csu.csuname
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
Select CSU.*, Sum (LOAN.arears) As totalArears FROM CSU Left Join LOAN On CSU.csuid = LOAN.csuid Group By (CSU.csuname)
```